# LINQ With multiple AND and OR Operations

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I am trying to select those models which meet the following conditions:

      All models which do not have strShortcuts as dto.ShortCut and strModel as dto.Model EXCEPT the 
   ones which have the same idxModel as dto.Idx

```
var duplicate = _modelRepository.QueryWhere( dup=> dup.idxModel != dto.Idx 
                                                  && ( dup.strShortCut == dto.ShortCut 
                                                       || dup.strModel == dto.Model
                                                     )
                                           )
                                .FirstOrDefault();
```

Am I constructing the query correct?

Comment: Is `QueryWhere` your own method? Does the query return what you expect?

Comment: All models which **do not** have ... `dup.strShortCut == dto.ShortCut`. If you want them to be not equal change your query inside parenthesis to this one: `dup.strShortCut != dto.ShortCut && dup.strModel != dto.Model`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what QueryWhere is but besides that, you should check for:

```
var duplicate = _modelRepository.QueryWhere( dup=> dup.idxModel != dto.Idx 
                                                  && !( dup.strShortCut == dto.ShortCut 
                                                       || dup.strModel == dto.Model)
                                           )
```

...or better:

```
var duplicate = _modelRepository.QueryWhere( dup=> dup.idxModel != dto.Idx 
                                                  && ( dup.strShortCut != dto.ShortCut 
                                                       && dup.strModel != dto.Model)
                                           )
```

And skip the 'FirstOrDefault' as it would not give you 'all' models but, as the function name says, the first one or default (null)

Comment: QueryWhere() returns all entities that meet the given condition.
@michael-r